# How to add a view to UINavigationController that is visible above any child view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm creating an app which shows data in a UITableView. This data also contains location information, so I want to add a MapView to display this data. When a user taps a UITableViewCel, I need to segue to another UITableView to show the detailed data. I still want to show the MapView with the same data above this detailed data, and I still want the NavigationBar to update, i.e. the back buttons returns the user to the first UITableView.

In image form to make it easier to understand

[image: DetailView of UINavigationController]

I was thinking of making a subclass of a UINavigationController and putting the container underneath the MapView, but I don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: did you put the mapView and the tableView under UIViewController?

Comment: you can do this with `self.title` in viewdidload method and pass the data to your second vc with prepareforsegue method.

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to segue from the first TableView to the second while still using the same MapView and being able to use the NavigationBar to go back to the first TableView.

Comment: How do you show the data in first view, do you use any model or just an array with strings.

Comment: It's an array, which is retrieved from the model.

Comment: if you have put mapview in one viewcontroller through storyboard then in another viewcontroller you need to put another mapview. the flow you want is not a good idea. so place two mapview in different view.

Comment: But the map views show the same information, which would cause an unnecessary instance of the MapView to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Have VC0 embedded in a navigation controller or subclass UINavigationController.  Create an Info ViewController and push that on the navigation controller.

In your particular case you'll want to use the didSelectRowAt method from UITableViewDelegate.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  // use indexPath.section and indexPath.row to use your data
  let infoVC = yourInfoViewController()
  infoVC.title = "Info Cell Name"
  navigationController?.pushViewController(infoVC, animated: true)
}
```

---

*Edit after first comment:*

I'm not sure what the best way of doing this is but one way you can do it is:

- Modify your table view based on what is being shown, ie: first set of data or cell detail data
- Update the navigation bar's title and left bar buttons per set of data you're displaying

  - One of those buttons will only appear in the cell detail data set and it sets your switch back to displaying the first set of data

Comment: But I want to keep using the same map view, so I don't have to instantiate a new one.